# Choosing which Form Runner button is the primary button

Tags: orbeon

Is there a way to change which of the Form Runner buttons is styled as the primary button?

I have changed the order of the buttons on a form using the `oxf.fr.detail.buttons.` property, so the submit is on the left instead of the right, so I need to be able to set the left button as the primary button (and colored as such).

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.APP.*">
  submit
  cancel
</property>
```

I can hack the CSS, but would like to do it from Orbeon as orbeon sets the classes on these buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary button is currently always set to be the last, that is the rightmost button. So no, it's not possible to change this without making changes to Form Runner proper.

Each process button does have a `fr-<type>-button` class, eg `fr-submit-button` that you can use to style a specific button a specific way. Except in Orbeon Forms 2016.1 (https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2739).